# Summation of a function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, mpmath

I'm new to Python programming. Coming from a MATLAB background. I'm looking something similar to symsum function from MATLAB in Python.

I have my array,

```
a = np.linspace([0,3.14])
```

I want to sum

```
sin(2*i*a) where i ranges from 1 to 20
```

and then plot the results between a and y

I tried the following

`y = nsum(lambda i: np.sin(2*i*a), [0,20])`

I'm stuck at this point.

Edit. The MATLAB equivalent would be

`a = linspace(0,pi)
syms i
 y=double(symsum(sin(2*i*a),i,0,20)`

Comment: `[0, 20]` produces a two-element list that contains elements 0 and 20. To get a list of numbers from 1 to 20 use `range(1, 21)` (remember that in Python things are 0-based). did you try just using the Python `sum` function? Are you sure that you want to compute the sum? Since you want to plot `a` vs. `y` it seems maybe you want to just evaluate at each element in `a`?

Comment: It might help if you showed working MATLAB/Octave code.  Then I could try to replicate it with `numpy`.

Comment: why mpmath tag?

Comment: @Daniel Junglas yes. I want to just evaluate at each element in `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj I used `mpmath` because of the `nsum`. I've edited the question to include the equivalent MATLAB code.

Comment: `mpmath` is often used with `sympy`, but rarely with `numpy`.  So the source of `nsum` was not obvious.

Comment: @hpaulj I really appreciate it. This is my Day 1 in Python world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### edit

Looks like `symsum` is part of a symbolics package (in MATLAB and Octave).  `sympy` is the Python symbolics package.  Its integration with `numpy` is looser.

===

Here's a guess as to what you are trying to do:

A range of `a` values:

```
In [180]: a = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
```

Outer product with (0,1,2,3,4) (uses broadcasting)

```
In [181]: x = np.arange(5)[:,None]*a
```

Sum the `sin` values, and plot:

```
In [182]: y = np.sin(2*x).sum(axis=0)                                                        
In [184]: plt.plot(a,y)
```

[image: sum of 5 sins]